# Regex to match text between two unclosed tags in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code:

```
<br>
                For Day October 21, 2013, The following locations have been restricted<br>
                <br>
                 No increases in nominations sourced from points west of Southeast for delivery to points east of Southeast, except for Primary Firm No-Notice nominations, will be accepted.<br>
```

I want to match the text that is between all occurrences of `<br><br>` tags like i need output as:

```
For Day October 21, 2013, The following locations have been restricted
No increases in nominations sourced from points west of Southeast for delivery to points east of Southeast, except for Primary Firm No-Notice nominations, will be accepted.
```

Please suggest me a proper regular expression for this

Comment: Are you trying to parse/extract data from a html file? Try http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732395#1732395

Comment: that might be a bit hard using Regex as the tags are the same - I'm not sure how you can do it without grabbing everything

Comment: Obligatory and related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you need Regular Expression?

Try something like

```
string output = sourceHtml.Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine).Trim();
```

This will remove the `<br>` tags and give you your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegexTester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var text = @"<br>
                For Day October 21, 2013, The following locations have been restricted<br>
                <br>
                 No increases in nominations sourced from points west of Southeast for delivery to points east of Southeast, except for Primary Firm No-Notice nominations, will be accepted.<br>";

            var pattern = "<br>\\s*";

            var result = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, string.Empty);

            Console.WriteLine(result);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```